# What does knockout mean?

Tags: process

I've been reading the [How To Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com) book, which is generally good, but the author uses the term "knockout" without definition a couple of times. What does it mean?

Comment: could someone with more rep add a "terminology" tag... a "defects" tag would also help.

Comment: I'm surprised this term isn't in the Homebrew Talk wiki (or any other I know of). Guess I'll make a page over there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this page](http://brewersroundtable.com/knockout-t895.html), it's the very end of the boil.  Minute 0.

Comment: Ever feel like you're talking to yourself? ;)

Comment: It must be true, it's recorded in a wiki: http://homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Knockout

Answer (score 5):

Yep.  It's when you shut off the burner (or heat source) on your boil kettle.  You "knock-out" the flame.

Comment: Also called flameout!

Answer (score 1):

Knocking out is when you chill the wort. For example I knocked out to 18˚C so I could pitch my yeast. Flame out is minute 0. For example I added 45g willamette hops at flame out to add aroma.

Comment: Your answer is not bad, but it brings nothing new. Downvote is not from me, but I kinda understand where it came from.